# How to get the if statement out of the loop if it satisfies the condition?

Tags: c, if-statement, printf, cs50, conditional-operator

I have written a code that prints out how many a's there are in a user input string.

I want the program to print out "There is a total of 1 a" instead of "There are a total of 1 a's".

I tried writing an if statement, but it prints out the length of the string in every loop. How can I adjust this? I've tried some things, but I did not get that far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    string input = get_string("Write something and I'll tell you how many a's there are: ");

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n ; i++){
        if (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'A'){
             count++;
        }
        if (count == 1){
            printf("\nThere is a total of %i a", count);
        }
    }

    printf("\nThere are a total of %i a's", count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    string input = get_string("Write something and I'll tell you how many a's there are: ");

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n ; i++)
        if ((input[i] | 0x20) == 'a')
            count++;

    (count == 1) ? printf("\nThere is a total of 1 a") : printf("\nThere are a total of %i a's", count);

}
```

Using a [ternary operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

NB:  ('a' or 0x20) as well as ('A' or 0x20) equal 'a'

Comment: I don't know what ternary is yet since I haven't come across it with the course, but I'll definitely look into this! It did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I added the wikipedia link that explains it!

Comment: `NB: ('a' or 0x20) as well as ('A' or 0x20) equal 'a'` - is is only if system is using ASCII.  Not portable and naive. @ano - avoid this micro pseudo optimization as a plaque. They look "hacky" but they are not.

Answer (score 1):

You could write using the if tatement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    string input = get_string("Write something and I'll tell you how many a's there are: ");

    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n ; i++){
        if (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'A'){
             count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 1){
        printf("\nThere is a total of %i a", count);
    }
    else {
        printf("\nThere are a total of %i a's", count);
    }
}
```

Or you could use the conditional operator

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    string input = get_string("Write something and I'll tell you how many a's there are: ");

    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n ; i++){
        if (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'A'){
             count++;
        }
    }


    printf("\nThere %s a total of %i a%s", 
           count == 1 ? "is" : "are", 
           count, 
           count == 1 ? "" : "'s" );
}
```

A third approach can use a string literal that specifies the format string. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    string input = get_string("Write something and I'll tell you how many a's there are: ");

    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n ; i++){
        if (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'A'){
             count++;
        }
    }

    string format;

    if (count == 1){
        format = "\nThere is a total of %i a";
    }
    else {
        format = "\nThere are a total of %i a's";
    }

    printf( format, count );
}
```

Comment: Please Vlad, can you  illustrate me and explain me when was the `string` type introduced in C.  I'm sure you know it's from a recent standard, but I'm not aware of it.  Where can I get info about this type unknown for me.  Thanks in advance.  (it confounds me from the c++ `string` type, but you cannot apply `strlen()` to it, so I feel it's an alias for `char *`, is it?)

Comment: @LuisColorado The type string is a typedef alias for the type char ( defined in the header  <cs50.h>

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just take this line out of the for loop

```
if (count == 1){
    printf("\nThere is a total of %i a", count);
}
```

Then construct a conditional statement like this outside of the loop

```
if (count == 1){
    printf("\nThere is a total of %i a", count);
}else if(count > 1){
    printf("\nThere are a total of %i a's", count);
}else{
    printf("\nThere are no a's");
}
```

This is how your final code should like

```
int main(void){
int ctr = 0;
string input = get_string("Write something and I'll tell you how many a's there are: ");

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input) ; i++){

    if (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'A'){
         count++;
    }

    //Where you removed the if (count == 1)

}

//Where it should be
if (count == 1){
    printf("\nThere is a total of %i a", count);
}else if(count > 1){
    printf("\nThere are a total of %i a's", count);
}else{
    printf("\nThere are no a's");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to come out of the loop after a satisfying condition you can use `break` statement it will get you out of the inner loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    string input = get_string("Write something and I'll tell you how many a's there are: ");
    

    for (size_t i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n ; i++)
        count += (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'A');
    
    printf("\nThere is a total of %i a%s", count, count == 1 ? "" :"'s");

}
```